# Logical operator with Arithmetic operator in C

Tags: c, logical-operators

I came across a question and I wanted to verify whether my assumptions were correct.

Given the following codes:

```
1.    int i = -2, j = 1, ans;
2.    ans = i++ || ++j;
3.    printf("%d %d %d", i,j, ans);
```

**The output is: `-1 1 1`**

In C language, it seems that only `0` will be treated as false, any other values will be treated as true when used with a logical operator. So I am not doubtful why ans derives to `1` (true || true gives us true(1) )

**What I wanted to ask here is:** Why is the value of `j` still `1` and not `2` despite `++j`?
Can safely assume that **any** arithmetic operations after the logical operators `||` `&&` will only be effective at the line it is used(in this case, line 2), and after which the variable still retain its original value?

Comment: Are you aware of [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)?

Answer (score 2):

`||` operator wont do any operation on second operand when first operand is `nonzero`.

Because, any one of the operand is `non-zero` then, output will be `true` in `||` operator operation. In your code 1st operand is `non-zero`. Thats why operation on second operand is not performed.

Answer (score 1):

As in Second Line of your Code i.e

```
ans = i++ || ++j;
```

first it will check `i++` as it is not zero that means it is true.
And in `OR` Condition if first condition is true it will not check second condition i.e `++j`.

Because if first condition is true is doesn't matter, Second condition is TRUE or FALSE it will return a true value. So if First Condition is true it will not check the other condition.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this right, if we changed `i=-2` to `i=-1` in the first line, the output is: `0 2 1`?

Comment: Computer says no.  Why does `j` not get incremented in this case?

Comment: @AndyJ0076 No, It Should print `0 1 1` as first it will evaluate value of `i` i.e -1 and return `TRUE` and so not check `j++`. At last it will perform `i++`.

Comment: @AndyJ0076 try with `i=0` and `j=1` then it will check `j++` and return `1 2 1`.

Comment: @AndyJ0076 Or Simply try `print("%d", i++);`, You can see First it will print value of `i` then perform `i++`.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So in the original example, `i` is tested on the second line, then incremented, then printed on the third line?

Answer (score 0):

Logical operators short circuit. That is, in the following:

```
ans = i++ || ++j;
```

`++j` will never be evaluated if `i++` evaluates to true (non-zero).